# How load a list of object in a Entity by Nhibernate Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lazy-evaluation, lazy-loading

I have a project by NHibernate implementation and using Lazy Loading.
I have two class in this project : Person and Family.
Relation between Those two is aggregation, is mean a Person has a list of Person.
Maping is :

```
  <class name="Person" table="Person_Person" >

    <id name="Id" type="Int64" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <bag name="Families" inverse="true" table="Person_Family" cascade="delete" >
      <key column="Person_id_fk"/>
      <one-to-many class="Domain.Entities.Family,RCISP.Domain.Entities"/>
    </bag>

  </class>
```

In this project, I Get a person by ID then add a family to families field in Person and save Person.

```
Person person = SessionInstance.Get<Person>(id);
Family family = new Family();
family.Name = "Ehsan";
person.Families.Add(family);
SessionInstance.Save(person);
```

Person saved in database, but family does not apply, Because lazy loading is active. But if before add a family, Execute count on families, my problem is resolved.

```
int i = person.Families.Count; //Provisional For call in lazy loading
person.Families.Add(family);
SessionInstance.Save(person);
```

How can i add a family to person without directly load families of person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change your cascade style on your `Families` collection to `all-delete-orphan` or `all`

```
<bag name="Families" inverse="true" table="Person_Family" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
      <key column="Person_id_fk"/>
      <one-to-many class="Domain.Entities.Family,RCISP.Domain.Entities"/>
</bag>
```

Comment: I tested it. By change , this problem is resolved, But there was another problem. by this change i can not delete a family. during remove family of Person is a exception by this message : 
`deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)`

Comment: this change does not interfere with the lazy approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means?  This does not affect lazy loading.